# How to combine member of list vector within a list

Tags: r, list

I have the following list of list:

```
nfoo <- list(a = list(x = 1:3, y = 11:13), b = list(x = 1:3, y = 100:102))
```

It looks like this:

```
 > nfoo
$a
$a$x
[1] 1 2 3

$a$y
[1] 11 12 13


$b
$b$x
[1] 1 2 3

$b$y
[1] 100 101 102
```

What I want to do is to combine the list within the list, resulting:

```
$a
[1] 1 2 3 11 12 13

$b
[1] 1 2 3 100 101 102
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `lapply` with `unlist`

```
lapply(nfoo, unlist, use.names = FALSE)

#$a
#[1]  1  2  3 11 12 13

#$b
#[1]  1   2   3 100 101 102
```

Using `purrr`, we can do that by using `map` and `flatten.*`

```
library(purrr)
map(nfoo, flatten_int)
```

Answer (score 2):

If we know that each of the sublists of `foo` contain vectors `x` and `y` (which is true for the example in the question) then:

```
lapply(foo, with, c(x, y))
```

giving:

```
$a
[1]  1  2  3 11 12 13

$b
[1]   1   2   3 100 101 102
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `lapply` with `docall` and the concatenate function (which also works with lists):

```
output <- lapply(nfoo, function(x) do.call(c, x))
output

$a
x1 x2 x3 y1 y2 y3 
 1  2  3 11 12 13 

$b
 x1  x2  x3  y1  y2  y3 
  1   2   3 100 101 102
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `lapply` to iterate through your list and then `unlist` to make each into a vector:

```r
lapply(nfoo, unlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
nfoo%>%map(unlist)

# $a
# x1 x2 x3 y1 y2 y3 
#  1  2  3 11 12 13 
# 
# $b
#  x1  x2  x3  y1  y2  y3 
#   1   2   3 100 101 102
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, there is another variant which uses `Reduce()` within `lapply()`

```
lapply(nfoo, Reduce, f = c)
```

> ```
> $a
> [1]  1  2  3 11 12 13
>
> $b
> [1]   1   2   3 100 101 102
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Using `do.call`.

```
Map(do.call, nfoo, w="c")
# $a
# x1 x2 x3 y1 y2 y3 
#  1  2  3 11 12 13 
# 
# $b
# x1  x2  x3  y1  y2  y3 
#  1   2   3 100 101 102
```